# Python Core Splitting multiprocessing

Tags: python, sql, multithreading

I'm using python to perform complicated SQL queries and append results in a single dataframe. I'm performing the same query just over many sql databases with a simple replace the database name from a list. Is there any way to speed this up? I have several cores in my computer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use joblib.parallel (https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html).

e.g.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def your_function_that_queries(your_functions_input1,your_functions_input_2,sql_name):
    foo(your_functions_input1,your_functions_input_2)
    resultblock = bar()
    return resultblock

temp_results = Parallel(n_jobs=number_of_parallel_processes_you_want)(delayed(your_function_that_queries)(your_functions_input1,your_functions_input_2,sql_name) for sql_name in sql_list)

# now process the list of resultblocks returned by Parallel
#e.g.
for resultblock in temp_results:
    pd.Dataframe.append or something
```

just watch out for the odd formatting in Parallels function call, being delayed(function)(functionparameters) and not delayed(function(functionparameters)).